# Python encapsulate data for a class

Tags: python

I have two python classes, A and B that inherits from A.
At runtime, I only have one instance of class A, but many instances of class B.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def _init2 (self, AA)
    self.a = AA.a

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, AA, b):
    super()._init2(AA)
    self.b = b

AA = A(0)
BB = B(AA, 1)
```

Is this the good way of writing it ? It seems ugly ...

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to remove `init2` and only use `__init__`. Having both is confusing and unnatural.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, obj):
    # I believe that this is what you tried to achieve
    if isinstance(obj, type(self)):
        self.a = obj.a    
    else:
        self.a = obj

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, A, b):
    super().__init__(A)
    self.b = b
```

On a side note, there are too many things called `A` here. The `A` in `def __init__(self, A, b):` is most probably not referring to the `A` that you expect.

Comment: Well, I can't. The two init function don't have the same signature. There is a confusion on A, I edited my code.